# Installed domain-based Multisite but can't access wp-admin (redirect loop)

Tags: multisite, database, redirect

I've installed a domain-based Multisite on my server, and everything works including each of the subdomains. Here I should explain that I imported a Database that was on my Local Mac, and then changed the details in the database for each site. However, I now can't access wp-admin for the main domain or any of the subdomains, Chrome just tells me there is a Redirect Loop (http://cl.ly/Qg7K). Let me just clarify that I can't access wp-admin at all, i.e not even the login page.

I'm reasonably confident with Wordpress, Databases and servers, so I can most likely get any data back for you and carry things out to test, try to fix etc.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**: People asked for my .htaccess code. It was copied from my localhost installation but I was using a Virtual Host so there were no paths involved. I'm no expert with .htaccess though so something could be wrong.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Check your `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are something doesn't line up in the database. The values in `wp_options->site_url` should the an exact match for the `wp_blogs->domain + path` values.

I made a post [here](http://ericholmes.ca/transferring-a-wordpress-multisite/) on the tables needed to change to transfer a multisite. Double-check these values.

For subdomain multisites, your domains should be `site1.domain.com` and path should be `/`, where your `site_url` should be `site1.domain.com/`.

Also, check your `wp_sitemeta->siteurl` value, and make sure it makes your blog1's values.

Comment: None of your advice seemed to make any difference :/ sorry :(

Comment: Is your wordpress directory in the root of the server? If not, make sure your subdriectory is in the `path` portion of data in `wp_blogs`, not in the domain.

Comment: Yeah it is in the root (public_html).

Comment: Does navigating the sites inner pages work fine? Event on subdomains? It could be an `.htaccess` issue. It's Rewrite Base should be `/`, so it could be messed up if copied from localhost (which would have the folder it was stored in MAMP on)

Comment: I've added my .htaccess code in the main question. It was copied from localhost but I was using a Virtual Host (e.g maindomain.dev, subdomain.maindomain.dev etc) so there were no paths.

Comment: Also, the individual pages on the main site and each subdomain site work as expected (i.e perfectly).

Comment: what about `mysite.com/wp-login.php` also giving the redirect loop?

Comment: I've had a lot of issues with transferring multisite, so I usually get my multisite set up with vanilla (for wp-config.php and .htaccess settings) and then rewrite the database after. Maybe disable multisite, and re-copy the `wp-config` and `.htaccess` settings they give you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a solution, but to fix this I reinstalled Wordpress (as Eric Holmes said in our discussion) and re-enabled Multisite, so the wp-admin section works. I then hooked up it to my previous database, installed my themes and everything now works as expected, as far as I can see. :)